# discrete maths/ cardinality of sets/ functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let
$n > m \geq 1$, $M=\{1,...,m\}$ and $N=\{1,...,n\}$. Furthermore, define the sets of all bijective mappings $f: N \to N$ with $F_n$.
Define

$A:=\{(a_1, \dots, a_n) | \{a_1,...,a_n\} \subset N\}$,

$B := \{(a_1, \dots, a_n) | \{a_1,...,a_n\} = N\}$,

$C := \{\{a_1, \dots, a_n\} | (a_1,...,a_n) \in A \text{/} B \}$

---

**State formulas for $|A|, |B|, |C|$ and order them by size.**

**How many $f \in F_n$ are there such that $f(M)=M$ (meaning that $f(i) \leq m$ is fulfilled for $i \leq m$)?**

Honestly I'm a little bit lost here, I know that I have to apply the binomial coefficient, but I do not know how to start. Don't quite understand the use of parentheses in the sets A/B/C. What exactly is $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$? Does $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ just denote the elements (or a subset thereof) of N?

Comment: Parentheses in this context imply sequences or ordered tuples as opposed to sets.  The formal definition of a sequence is a function from a set of integers ranging from $1$ to the length of the sequence $\{1,2,3,\dots,k\}$ to a codomain set.  Reworded, $|A|$ is the number of functions from $N$ to $N$ which don't necessarily use all of the codomain.  $|B|$ is the number of functions from $N$ to $N$ who *do* use all elements of the codomain.  $|C|$ is awkwardly written... are you sure you don't mean to write $C=\{\color{red}{(}a_1,\dots,a_n\color{red}{)}|(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in A\setminus B\}$?

Comment: It should be clear that $B$ is simply the set of bijections $N\to N$ and is otherwise written in the question as $F_n$.  (*As an aside, many other authors call this $S_n$, the "symmetric group"*).  $A$ is the set of all functions $N\to N$ (*and is commonly written by other authors as $N^N$*).  If I am correct in that you have a typo for $C$, then $C$ is the functions from $N\to N$ who aren't bijections.  The quantities for each should be well known, or found by use of fundamental principles such as the multiplication or addition principles of counting.

Comment: @JMoravitz: thank you so so much for your detailed explanations. For B the number of bijections would be $n!$? for A would it be $n^n$? I checked again for C, there is no typo from my side here, but very possible that there was a type in my course notes. would C be just the difference of A and B? so $n^n - n!$?

Comment: Quite.  If it really has no typo... then it would be worded as "the set of possible ranges of non-bijective functions $N\to N$" which would be all non-trivial proper subsets of $N$ and would be of size $2^n-2$... but I seriously doubt that is what is intended given the flavor of the other two sets.

Comment: @JMoravitz: thank you, I will ask my prof later in regards to that. could you help me solving the second part of the question, ($f(M)=M$) so f are the bijective mappings on N, and $M \subset N$, but how could I proceed here?

Comment: First, find a bijection $M\to M$ to handle how $f$ acts on the "first $m$ domain elements."  Then for the remaining domain elements, choose which of the $n$ codomain elements they map to, keeping in mind that we are talking about bijections here.  Reworded, concatenate a bijection from $M\to M$ with a bijection from $(N\setminus M)\to (N\setminus M)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: thank you for the explanation, but it is not very clear to me yet, so I could first chose the "natural" bijection.. $M \to M$ $f(i)=i, i \in M$ , and the remaining objects in N\M would be $\{m+1,...,n\}$ (since $m <n$)? But I still do not quite understand it yet

Comment: Suppose $m=9$ and $n=20$ or so... Now... examples of such functions would be $(\underbrace{1,2,3,\dots,9}_{\text{one-digit numbers}},\underbrace{10,11,\dots,20}_{\text{two-digit numbers}})$ or $(\underbrace{2,4,6,8,1,3,\dots,9}_{\text{one-digit numbers}},\underbrace{20,19,\dots,10}_{\text{two-digit numbers}})$ and so on... the one-digit numbers (*i.e. the numbers from $M$*) get permuted amongst themselves and occupy the first $m$ positions while the remaining two-digit numbers (*elements of $N\setminus M$*) get permuted amongst themselves occupying the later positions.

Comment: @JMoravitz: thank you so much for your very nice example, now it is clear, so the number of the first m permutations would be $m!$, next I would need a permutation on the remaining items which would be $(n-m)!$? for the final result, does the two have to be multiplicated with each other? so $m!(n-m)!$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collating comments:

The parentheses notation is typically used for sequences or ordered-tuples of numbers, which are formally defined as functions from an index set of the form $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ to whatever codomain set.  One can thus refer to sequences and functions interchangeably depending on preference.  I will refer to these as functions for the remainder of the post.

$A$ is talking about the set of functions $N\to N$ and is of size $n^n$.  *Side note:* Some authors will notate the set of functions $A\to B$ as $B^A$ which has the nice benefit of being able to say $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$

$B$ is talking about the set of functions $N\to N$ such that the range is the entirety of the codomain, i.e. here since $N$ is finite we have these are precisely the bijections $N\to N$.  Earlier in your post you were given the notation $F_n$ for this.  Many other authors prefer the notation $S_n$ in reference to the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group).  There are $n!$ such functions.

$C$ if written as is is either talking about the number of possible ranges of non-bijective functions $N\to N$ which would be all possible subsets of $N$ apart from the empty set and apart from the set $N$ itself.  In the case of $n\geq 2$ that would be $2^n-2$ (*and in the case of $n=0,1$ would be zero*).

If $C$ were a typo and meant to be $\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)|(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in A\setminus B\}$ instead, that is the set of functions $N\to N$ who are not bijections, that would be the difference of the previous two, $n^n-n!$.

Typically there will be many more non-bijections than bijections, making the hierarchy here $|B|\leq |C|\leq |A|$, though some small values of $n$ may mess with that.

---

As for counting those $f\in F_n$ satisfying $f(M)=M$, those would be the bijective functions such that the first $m$ positions are occupied by a permutation of the elements of $M$ and the remaining positions are occupied by a permutation of what remains.  It will indeed be $m!(n-m)!$ such functions.

Comment: thank you again very much for your help and time.